# CALayer position contains NaN when presenting BottomSheet in Two ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have 2 `UIViewController` and both of it has BottomSheet presented when pressing certain button. Let's say the ViewControllerA is navigated to ViewControllerB. When I open ViewController A, then navigate to ViewControllerB, and I present BottomSheet in ViewControllerB, it crashed. Here's the full message I got:

> Exception NSException *   "CALayer position contains NaN: [nan 438.667].
> Layer: <CALayer:0x6000029781e0; position = CGPoint (0 0); bounds =
> CGRect (0 0; 199.667 48); delegate = <_UIEditMenuListView:
> 0x138e26420; frame = (-99.8333 -24; 199.667 48); alpha = 0; layer =
> <CALayer: 0x6000029781e0>>; sublayers = (<CALayer: 0x600002978200>);
> opaque = YES; opacity = 0; shadowOpacity = 0.25; shadowOffset = CGSize
> (0 3); shadowRadius = 12>"    0x0000600002470fc0

The error doesn't occured when I open the ViewController separately without have to navigate to each other and the ViewControllerA doesn't have a BottomSheet. Here's the code of my BottomSheet.

```
public protocol MSBottomSheetListDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didFinishedPickingValue(value: String, index: Int)
}

public class MSBottomSheetList: UIViewController {
    let tableView: MSTableView = MSTableView()
    var selectedValue: String = ""
    var selectedIndex: Int = 0
    public var delegate: MSBottomSheetListDelegate?
    var dataArray: [String] = [""]
    
    lazy var titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Bottom Sheet Title"
        label.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        return label
    }()
    
    lazy var buttonDone: MSButtonContained = {
        let button: MSButtonContained = MSButtonContained()
        button.setTitle("Pilih", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(MSColorFoundation.msCarbonStrong, for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()
    
    lazy var contentStackView: UIStackView = {
        let spacer = UIView()
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [tableView, buttonDone])
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 12.0
        return stackView
    }()
    
    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        return view
    }()
    
    let maxDimmedAlpha: CGFloat = 0.6
    lazy var dimmedView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        view.alpha = maxDimmedAlpha
        return view
    }()
    
    // Constants
    let defaultHeight: CGFloat = 300
    let dismissibleHeight: CGFloat = 200
    let maximumContainerHeight: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 64
    // keep current new height, initial is default height
    var currentContainerHeight: CGFloat = 300
    
    // Dynamic container constraint
    var containerViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var containerViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    
    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupView()
        setupConstraints()
        // tap gesture on dimmed view to dismiss
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleCloseAction))
        dimmedView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        
        setupPanGesture()
    }
    
    @objc func handleCloseAction() {
        animateDismissView()
    }
    
    public override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        animateShowDimmedView()
        animatePresentContainer()
    }
    
    public func setListData(data: [String]) {
        dataArray = data
    }
    
    func setupView() {
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.center = self.view.center
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        buttonDone.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonDoneTapped) , for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    func setupConstraints() {
        // Add subviews
        view.addSubview(dimmedView)
        view.addSubview(containerView)
        dimmedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        containerView.addSubview(contentStackView)
        contentStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // Set static constraints
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // set dimmedView edges to superview
            dimmedView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            dimmedView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            dimmedView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            dimmedView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            // set container static constraint (trailing & leading)
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            // content stackView
            contentStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 32),
            contentStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
            contentStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            contentStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            
            buttonDone.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentStackView.leadingAnchor),
            buttonDone.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentStackView.trailingAnchor),
            
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentStackView.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentStackView.leadingAnchor)
        ])
        
        containerViewBottomConstraint = containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: defaultHeight)
        containerViewHeightConstraint?.isActive = true
        containerViewBottomConstraint?.isActive = true
    }
    
    func setupPanGesture() {
        // add pan gesture recognizer to the view controller's view (the whole screen)
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePanGesture(gesture:)))
        // change to false to immediately listen on gesture movement
        panGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = false
        panGesture.delaysTouchesEnded = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }

    // MARK: Pan gesture handler
    @objc func handlePanGesture(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
        // Drag to top will be minus value and vice versa
        print("Pan gesture y offset: \(translation.y)")
        
        // Get drag direction
        let isDraggingDown = translation.y > 0
        print("Dragging direction: \(isDraggingDown ? "going down" : "going up")")
        
        // New height is based on value of dragging plus current container height
        let newHeight = currentContainerHeight - translation.y
        
        // Handle based on gesture state
        switch gesture.state {
        case .changed:
            // This state will occur when user is dragging
            if newHeight < maximumContainerHeight {
                // Keep updating the height constraint
                containerViewHeightConstraint?.constant = newHeight
                // refresh layout
                view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        case .ended:
            // This happens when user stop drag,
            // so we will get the last height of container
            
            // Condition 1: If new height is below min, dismiss controller
            if newHeight < dismissibleHeight {
                self.animateDismissView()
            }
            else if newHeight < defaultHeight {
                // Condition 2: If new height is below default, animate back to default
                animateContainerHeight(defaultHeight)
            }
            else if newHeight < maximumContainerHeight && isDraggingDown {
                // Condition 3: If new height is below max and going down, set to default height
                animateContainerHeight(defaultHeight)
            }
            else if newHeight > defaultHeight && !isDraggingDown {
                // Condition 4: If new height is below max and going up, set to max height at top
                animateContainerHeight(maximumContainerHeight)
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    @objc func buttonDoneTapped() {
        animateDismissView()
        delegate?.didFinishedPickingValue(value: selectedValue, index: selectedIndex)
    }
    
    func animateContainerHeight(_ height: CGFloat) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            // Update container height
            self.containerViewHeightConstraint?.constant = height
            // Call this to trigger refresh constraint
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
        // Save current height
        currentContainerHeight = height
    }
    
    // MARK: Present and dismiss animation
    func animatePresentContainer() {
        // update bottom constraint in animation block
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.containerViewBottomConstraint?.constant = 0
            // call this to trigger refresh constraint
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    
    func animateShowDimmedView() {
        dimmedView.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            self.dimmedView.alpha = self.maxDimmedAlpha
        }
    }
    
    func animateDismissView() {
        // hide blur view
        dimmedView.alpha = maxDimmedAlpha
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            self.dimmedView.alpha = 0
        } completion: { _ in
            // once done, dismiss without animation
            self.dismiss(animated: false)
        }
        // hide main view by updating bottom constraint in animation block
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.containerViewBottomConstraint?.constant = self.defaultHeight
            // call this to trigger refresh constraint
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}

extension MSBottomSheetList: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }
    
    public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
          let row = dataArray[row]
          return row
    }
}

extension MSBottomSheetList: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }
    
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath
        ) as? UITableViewCell else {
            fatalError()
        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as UITableViewCell
        selectedValue = currentCell.textLabel?.text ?? ""
        selectedIndex = indexPath?.row ?? 0
    }
}
```

And here is my code to present the BottomSheet on my ViewController.

```
let bottomSheetDatePicker = MSBottomSheetDatePicker()
bottomSheetDatePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.present(bottomSheetDatePicker, animated: false)
```

Several things I've tried to solve it, but it still produce the same error:

1. Dismiss the BottomSheet in ViewWillDissapear.
2. Set the fix height on the BottomSheet and everything in it.

Answer (score 0):

This line is a problem. Why are you setting the center property on the tableView when you are using autolayout? Also, are you sure that you want your tableView in a stackView?

```
tableView.center = self.view.center
```

Also, in setupConstraints you activated containerViewHeightConstraint without creating it. containerViewHeightConstraint is nil.

```
containerViewHeightConstraint?.isActive = true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but after removing both the lines the error still occured.